# How to create a custom select command to select by option value in cypress

Tags: cypress

For the following html,

```
             <select class="cell dropdown" data-test="Visibility-warn">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <!---->
                <option value="0"><!---->Good<!----></option>
                <!---->
                <option value="1"><!---->Moderate/Good<!----></option>
                <!---->
                <option value="2"><!---->Moderate<!----></option>
                <!---->
                <option value="3" selected=""><!---->Moderate/Poor<!----></option>
                <!---->
                <option value="4"><!---->Poor<!----></option>
                <!---->
            </select>
```

I have written the cypress code to select by value and not by text. *As per [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Value), both select by text and select by value can be done in the same way.*

```
        cy.get('[data-test="Visibility-warn"]')
                .should('be.enabled')
                .select('3')
```

which works fine.

But on the other hand, I am trying to create a custom command that does not work.

```
 cy.selectAndVerify('[data-test="Visibility-warn"]', weatherLimits.Visibility.warn, 'Moderate/Poor');
 //weatherLimits.Visibility.warn = gives the value 3
```

And in Commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectAndVerify', (selector, textToSelect, valueToVerify) => {
  cy.log(textToSelect)
  cy.get(selector)
    .should('be.enabled')
    .select(textToSelect)
  //.should('have.text', valueToVerify);
})
```

How can I possibly make the custom command work?

[image]

Comment: At which line of code that test is failing ? Is it this `.select(textToSelect)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is `weatherLimits.Visibility.warn` is passing a number that is `3` but cypress is expecting an string. so it should be `.select(textToSelect + "")`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "selectAndVerify",
  (selector, textToSelect, valueToVerify) => {
    cy.log(textToSelect)
    cy.get(selector)
      .should("be.enabled")
      .select(textToSelect + "")
      .should("have.text", valueToVerify)
  }
)
```

Comment: Ahh, I got it. But it works with `.select(textToSelect+"")`  and not with `.select("textToSelect")` as this one will not convert to text from number but considers textToSelect as a value itself.

Comment: Yes true. The idea is to change the number to string. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though @Alapan Das answer is already accepted, adding an answer that rightly does the "verify" part.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectAndVerify', (selector, textToSelect, valueToVerify) => {
  cy.get(selector)
    .should('be.enabled')
    .select(textToSelect + "")
  cy.get(selector).find('option:selected').should('have.text', valueToVerify)
})
```

and in test

```
cy.selectAndVerify('[data-test="Visibility-warn"]', weatherLimits.Visibility.warn, 'Moderate/Poor');
```